# Angular js - get url query params when url has # hash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, param

I have an url like this:

```
site.co/asd#antani?id=9
```

How do i get `id` value from this url dynamically and get the new value when it changes?

i tryed :

`console.log($routeParams);` and i got `Object {}` in console

thanks

Comment: @StarsSky lol you know it :D

Comment: Did you try `$location.search()`. it should return `{id: 9}`

Comment: @MaximShoustin i'm into a directive when i log $location.search() it's always empty object :( {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK i think i fixed it and it was to change URL

so to make `$routeParams` works i needed to call

```
site.com/asd?id=9#antani
```

instead of

```
site.co/asd#antani?id=9
```

hope it can help also if i don't like the url in that way :D

big thanks to all and if you have any better solution let me know please !

Comment: Right, this is a proper form

Comment: yeah i don't like how it looks url but is the only right way i think

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't know your full Env. I would go to this dirtection:

```
var s = $location.search('site.co/asd#antani?id=9');

console.log(s.$$search);
```

Output:

```
Object {site.co/asd#antani?id: "9"}
```

Hope it will help,

Comment: this is quite good solution rly but it redirects me to strange url like in a loop i dunno why :( lso the ? is re-encoded  by browser or angular to %3F and i can't get why ufff :(

Answer (score 1):

Got a gist to do that and other useful functions on urls with params ( URL params to object, Test if url Has Params, get Hash without params, and Change url params)

https://gist.github.com/dazzer13/10470514

You can do this:

var params = urlGetParams(url);

params.id // returns 9

Answer (score 0):

```
var myURL = "site.co/asd#antani?id=9";
var myURL_id = myURL.split("#")[1];
```

Comment: thanks .. uhmm this quite basic i can parse it sure, i just would like to know if is out there some angular specifi method or way :P

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the actual page you are on, you can use angular [$routeParams](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/%24routeParams). Something like this:

```
var id = $routeParams.id
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to say i already tryed routeParams but it always return empty Object {} in console :( i updated my question

Comment: Hmm...are you injecting it into a controller or service? The $routeParams variable doesn't exist on the global scope in the console, same as any other angular service. You need to use dependency injection (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Comment: yeah ' injected both $location and $routeParams, but if i need some nested injection i'll avoid it i think anyway thanks :)

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by nested injection, but if you're injecting $routeParams and angular isn't throwing an error then it shouldn't be null inside that function. Can you print it using console.log or something?

Comment: console.log($routeParams); into directive returns Object {}

Comment: Hmm...sounds like there is something weird happening. Might need some more clarification, maybe you could post your code?

Comment: i'll try but it's rly too much code to paste dack :D i'll try

Comment: Maybe put it in a plunkr?

Comment: yep for sure man i just need to cut off many many parts not needed :P